# C: scanf() and while() (Programming Exercise 7.10 from C Primer Plus)

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm still reading Stephen Prata's "C Primer Plus". The following code is my attempt to solve the 10th programming exercise of the 7th chapter.
My Question: Why does the program loop infinitely when a character is entered instead of an integer and how can I prevent this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// taxrates
#define TAXRATE_1 .15
#define TAXRATE_2 .28
// category limits
#define SINGLE_LIMIT            17850
#define HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_LIMIT 23900
#define MARRIED_JOINT_LIMIT     29750
#define MARRIED_SEPARAT_LIMIT   14875
// bases
#define SINGLE_BASE             SINGLE_LIMIT            * TAXRATE_1
#define HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_BASE  HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_LIMIT * TAXRATE_1
#define MARRIED_JOINT_BASE      MARRIED_JOINT_LIMIT     * TAXRATE_1
#define MARRIED_SEPARAT_BASE    MARRIED_SEPARAT_LIMIT   * TAXRATE_1

int main(void)
{
    int selection;
    float income, tax;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("*******************************************************\n"
               "Please enter the number of your category:\n"
               "1) Single\n2) Head of Household\n3) Married, Joint\n4) Married, Separat\n5) quit\n"
               "*******************************************************\n");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        if (selection >= 1 && selection <= 4)
        {
            printf("Enter income: ");
            scanf("%f", &income);
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (income < SINGLE_LIMIT)
                        tax = income * TAXRATE_1;
                    else
                        tax = SINGLE_BASE           + (income - SINGLE_LIMIT) * TAXRATE_2;
                    printf("Single income of: %.2f$ Tax: %.2f$\n", income, tax);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (income < HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_LIMIT)
                        tax = income * TAXRATE_1;
                    else
                        tax = HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_BASE+ (income - HEAD_OF_HOUSEHOLD_LIMIT) * TAXRATE_2;
                    printf("Head of Household income of: %.2f$ Tax: %.2f$\n", income, tax);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (income < MARRIED_JOINT_LIMIT)
                        tax = income * TAXRATE_1;
                    else
                        tax = MARRIED_JOINT_BASE    + (income - MARRIED_JOINT_LIMIT) * TAXRATE_2;
                    printf("Married joint income of: %.2f$ Tax: %.2f$\n", income, tax);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (income < MARRIED_SEPARAT_LIMIT)
                        tax = income * TAXRATE_1;
                    else
                        tax = MARRIED_SEPARAT_BASE  + (income - MARRIED_SEPARAT_LIMIT) * TAXRATE_2;
                    printf("Married separat income of: %.2f$ Tax: %.2f$\n", income, tax);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (selection == 5)
        {
            printf("Done.");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 5.\n");
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Question: Why does the program loop infinitely when a character is
>   entered instead of an integer and how can I prevent this behavior.

When you input something is not expected by `scanf()` (as defined by the format string you pass to scanf), it ignores it and returns. But that invalid input is not cleared from the input stream. So the loop carries on forever as read-ignore-loop-again continues in your program.

So to address it:

- Avoid `scanf()` whenever possible. Use `fgets()` and process the input using `sscanf()`, which provides better error control.
- Check the return value `scanf()` to decide if the scanning was successful.

The usual way to clear is to read out all the characters in the input stream when you encounter invalid input:

```
else { 
       int c;
       printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 5.\n");
       while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ; /* reads and discards */
     }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the other functions have not been introduced yet. Do I understand this right: The unrecognised input from scanf() stays in the inputstream and is discarded once recognised by the getchar() (until '\n').

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. You can learn about those functions later then :) Just something to keep in mind about the imperfections of scanf() & why it's not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

While loop in the program exits when only when the value of selection in the else part is 5.
But whenever you will enter a character the value of selection can't be 5, so it never comes out of the loop and makes the program loop to run infinitely.

Comment: You must probably check the code by running it on your machine. Any integer value is valid i.e will not cause an infinite loop.

Comment: yes that's true that it can take any integer value but to exit from the while loop the value of the variable "selection" should be 5. If you must read the question carefully it is asked when a character is entered why it does not come out of the loop. Hope it is clear now

Comment: I wanted the loop to stop only if the value of selection is 5. Why cant I enter any new numbers once i entered a character? What happens to the scanf() after the first printf()? Why doesn't the program stop to wait for user input once a character is entered?